# Property of sets with finite Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A $ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be measurable with finite lebesgue measure. Show that there exists a countable family of open sets $U_{n}$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and a nullset $N$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $A = (\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} U_{i}) \setminus N$.

So I'm pretty sure that I have to use the following property:

For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $U$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ open and $V$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ closed such that $V \subseteq A \subseteq U$ and $\lambda_n(U \setminus V)<\epsilon$. I can't fit the pieces together so maybe someone can drop a tip.

Answer (score 0):

For each $i\in \mathbb{N}$ chose an open set $U_i$ that contains $A$ such that $\lambda_n(U_i \setminus A) < \frac{1}{i}$. Then $A \subseteq \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty U_i$ and for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$,
$$\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty U_i\right) \setminus A \subseteq U_k\setminus A$$
This shows that $$\lambda_n\left[\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty U_i\right) \setminus A\right] = 0$$
since it is less than $\frac{1}{k}$ for each $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Now notice that
$$A = \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty U_i\right)  \setminus \left[ \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty U_i\right) \setminus A\right]$$